# How does this multithreaded Java code work?

Tags: java, multithreading

Given this Java code:

```
class Account {
        private Integer number = 0;
        public synchronized void setNumber(Integer number) {
            this.number = number;
        }

         public synchronized Integer getNumber() {
            return number;
        }
    }

    class Client extends Thread {
        Account account;
        public Client(Account account) {
            this.account = account;
        }
        public  void run() {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
            account.setNumber(account.getNumber() + 1);
             }
        }
    }

    public class Run {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            Account account = new Account();
            Client one = new Client(account);
            Client two = new Client(account);
            one.start();
            two.start();
            one.join();
            two.join();
           System.out.println("Exiting main");
       System.out.println("account number value: " +account.getNumber());        
        }
    }
```

What is the value of `number` when the main method completes? Is it 2000 or less than 2000? I am getting less than 2000. How can two threads call `getNumer()` or `setNumber()` from `run()` at the same time, given that each one is synchronized?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Think carefully about what happens in the following section.

```
account.setNumber(account.getNumber() + 1);
```

Even though both methods are separately synchronized, the operation as a whole isn't.

Comment: You're welcome. If you have an answer to your question you should choose one of the answers as correct.

Answer (score 5):

It is possible for the number to be less than or equal to 2000, but never higher.  Consider that each of the "set" and "get" number functions are synchronized *separately* but they are not synchronized *together*.  This means that it is possible for a race condition between threads to "skip" calls to the combined "increment" effect.

Consider this possible sequence of calls between two threads:

```
number  Thread1     Thread2
0       get => 0    -
-       -           get => 0
-       -           incr => 1
1       -           set => 1
-       incr => 1   -
1       set => 1    -
```

Note that each thread got the number zero, incremented separately, and then set the number one.  Both threads believed that they incremented the number but their calls to set/get were interleaved so one of them was effectively skipped.

To contrast, try writing a third synchronized method in the Account class called `increment()` which does the get/increment/set sequence atomically and see that you will always get the number 2000.

Comment: Thanks Maerics for answering my question